# How to avoid joining MathieuCharacteristicA in a plot?

Tags: plotting, special-functions

In the documentation

> As a function of the first argument, MathieuCharacteristicA is a
>   piecewise continuous function

So how to avoid joining different pieces of the function? For example,

```
Plot[MathieuCharacteristicA[r, 1], {r, -2.5, 2.5}]
```

I get

[image]

So why does Mathematica draw the vertical lines in default? And how to avoid drawing them except using a explicit setting such as `Exclusions -> 1`?

Comment: I think the explicit use of exclusions is all you can hope for.

Comment: Exclusions -> Range[-2, 2]